# Looking for a Micro SD card that can start up in 1.8V signalling mode

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, sd

With the SD 6.0 specification, SD card manufactures have the option to design cards that can autodetect and start up with 1.8V signal levels.  I believe they still need to be powered from the nominal 3.3V range but the interface to the microcontroller no longer needs to start at 3.3V and then command the card to reduce to 1.8V signal levels.  I don't think this is inclusive of all SD 6.0 compliant cards, just an option is added to the specification.  If it does support startup with 1.8V signal levels, I think it needs to be marked with the "LV" stamp (if there is any room left with all of the other stamps - sarcastic, not really part of the spec).

With most of the microcontrollers manufactured in the past decade supporting 1.8V I/O, where are the SD cards that don't need level translators to start up at 1.8V.

Does anyone know of a MicroSD card that may not advertise its ability to start at 1.8V signaling but has this capability?

Comment: There was a similar question here recently. There do not appear to be commercially-available cards that support that standard. It's always possible any given 3.3V card might work with 1.8V because 1.8 > 3.3/2  (around where the typical threshold will be). Doesn't mean it will be reliable.

Comment: We have tested some with the power supply set slightly higher and it seems the threshold is just over 1.8V at room temp so not confident enough to call that a solution over full operating range.  It is strange that with all of the 1.8V microcontrollers that this is not more common product.

Comment: have you considered converting the 1.8V signals to 3.3V signals and back?

Comment: With 1.8V µC you would usually use eMMC and not the bigger SD cards. And if the user could change the card, you *need* to be able to use 3.3V cards.

Comment: The device is always under our control, so we do not have to worry about someone buying and trying to use an unsupported card, but we do need to the the card removable so eMMC is out.  Yes, we looked at level translators and they are easy to implement and the uC I am using has the direction control lines available too.  I just thought by now with all of the 1.8V processors that a product like this would be more available.

Answer (score 1):

Micron's i400 series supports LVS (low voltage signaling). Just for clarification, LVS means that the device can work in both 2.8 - 3.3 Volts and 1.75-2.something (I haven't tested personally) Volts ranges. But other than that, these are standard pinout sd cards.
The double row sd cards use LVDS (low voltage differential signaling). That's another discussion.

You can buy these at [Mouser](https://ro.mouser.com/new/micron-technology/micron-i400-microsd-cards/) (and probably digikey, farnell etc.).

[image]

Another mention, for 1.8V MCU's, are the nano memory cards.
[image]

These aren't actually SD cards, but eMMC chips packaged in a nano sim form factor. While these ics need 2.8 - 3.3 Volts, the IO lines work exclusively @ 1.8 volts.
The ADMA (advanced dma) enables transfers of up to 2040 sectors (2040 x 512 bytes) at a time and the power consumption is, if I remember correctly, somewhere in the 200 mW ballpark @ 48 mhz / 4 bit mode (write).
But, again, these are eMMCs, so you need a MMC host controller (most MCUs that have sdio have mmc capabilities though).

**EDIT**: I've personally tested the huawei card, on a couple of MCUs. The micron ones I've yet to test.
The nano memory cards aren't standard. They were first rolled out by huawei, AFAIK. But there are other brands out there. Like Lexmark, cheap chinese knock-offs etc. Not all of these are eMMC under the hood. Some are classic SD cards packaged in a nano sim form factor. And the 1.8V logic levels mention goes out the window.

Comment: Are these cards guatanteed to be able to start in 1.8V IO mode?

Comment: according to the spec, yes. The Huawei only works in 1.8volts mode (i mean the IO lines and IO lines alone. The vdd, as mentioned, is still 3v3).
the micron ones are LV50 / LV104 and *should* use, according to the spec, signaling to esablish the IO levels.